Why address of the files stored on disk (of vbox vm) are different each time i look at them?
I am aware of ASLR which loads the program at different memory locations each time, however, I am not sure why this is happening in the case of files that I have stored on disk /dev/sda2 of my Linux VM.
mp:projects-20:17:09-$ ./lseek_demo 
The end offset of file1 is 1268
The start  offset of file2 is 0
Diff between them is -1268
The mem address of file1 is 0x7ffce008e738
The mem address of file2 is 0x7ffce008e740


mp:projects-20:17:12-$ ./lseek_demo 
The end offset of file1 is 1268
The start  offset of file2 is 0
Diff between them is -1268
The mem address of file1 is 0x7fff9113e148
The mem address of file2 is 0x7fff9113e150

here is a code I am using
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <error.h>

void   offsets(const char* fname1,const char*  fname2)
{
        int fd0 = open(fname1, O_RDWR);
        int fd1 = open(fname2, O_RDWR);

        if (fd0 == -1 || fd1 == -1)
                perror("opne");

        off_t off_fd0 = lseek(fd0, -1, SEEK_END);
        off_t off_fd1 = lseek(fd1,0,SEEK_SET);


        close(fd0);
        close(fd1);

        printf ("The end offset of file1 is %ld\n The start  offset of file3 is %ld\n Diff between them is %ld\n",off_fd0, off_fd1,(off_fd1 - off_fd0));
        printf ("The mem address of file1 is %p\n The mem address of file2 is %p\n",&off_fd0,&off_fd1);
}

int main()
{
        offsets ("readme.txt","slack_space_calc.c");
        return 0;
}

This is compiled on ubuntu 6.8.0-38-generic #38-Ubuntu

Your file "mem address" is the address of a local variable in your function.

What is "the address of a file stored on disk"? You print the address of a pointer variable in your program. That is not related to the file at all. They are stored on the stack and the OS may assign whatever address it likes to your program.

Think of the & operator as the pointer to operator. Which means that e.g. &off_fd0 is a pointer to the variable off_fd0.

The difference between file offsets of two different files is completely useless and nonsensical. There's no relationship between the two.

The closest thing to a disk address is probably the inode.  See stat if you want to check it.

The offset you get from lseek is the number of bytes from the start of the file to the current position in the file, where the next read or write operation would access the file. The start offset is always 0, and the end offset is the file size in bytes.

Files don't have addresses to begin with.

This code:
        off_t off_fd0 = lseek(fd0, -1, SEEK_END);
        off_t off_fd1 = lseek(fd1,0,SEEK_SET);

declares two local variables of (some unspecified bitlength) signed integer type and sets them to the return values of the lseek()s. Those variables are forced to be stored on the stack by code further down; more on that in a moment.
The expression &off_fd0 returns a pointer to the off_fd0 variable, not the address of the "file". So, when you print it with %p, you are printing the memory address of that stack variable.
An interesting side note. If you removed that print statement, there's a good chance that the compiler would optimize out one or both variables. I.e. it would keep the return values of the lseek() calls in CPU registers. At that point, the variables have no address at all. (This depends on what compiler you're using, the target CPU architecture, and the optimization level chosen for the compile.) The presence of the expression &off_fd0 forced the compiler to allocate stack storage for that variable, and in the process made your code slightly less efficient than it could be.
As for why the address of those variable varies from one run to another. There was a time when that wasn't the case - every time you ran the program, the stack would be in the same place. Welcome to ASLR - even the stack gets moved around.
Finally, what about the address of the file itself? Well, it doesn't have a memory address, but you could say that the disk block numbers of the file's contents represent the "address" of the file. If you look at those, you will find that the files do not move around; they pretty much stay at the same place on the disk, although even that is not a hard-and-fast rule. If you want to find out those disk block numbers, then good luck. Each type of file system has its own way of getting at the info, and then there's RAIDs and NASes, and exploring all that is way beyond the scope of this answer.
